# Rehashing in a linear probe hash table in c

Tags: c, hash

In an attempt to learn hashing, I am trying to make a hash table where hashing is done by linear probing. I increase the size of the table whenever the load factor - alpha (filled buckets/total buckets) exceeds 0.75. Following is the code for the same. But the program stops in between when I execute it.
The confusing part is that sometimes the resizing of table occurs for a number of steps, while the other times it does not. The resizing is done in the rehashing function. It is required for the the initial table size to be 31 and go up till 8191.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define null 0
#define occupied 1
#define deleted 2
#define maxLen 8191

typedef struct cell
{
    int key;
    short flag;
} Cell;

void insert(Cell *a, Cell* copy, int key);
int search(Cell* a, int key);
void delete(Cell* a, int key);
void rehash(Cell* a, Cell* copy);
int nextPrime(int n);
int isPrime(int n);

int buckets = 31;
int filled = 0;
float alpha = 0.0;

int main()
{
    int i, total, val;
    printf("\nHashing with linear probing\n");
    printf("_______________________________________________________________\n\n");

    Cell *hashTable, *copy;
    hashTable = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));
    for (i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        hashTable[i].key = -100;
        hashTable[i].flag = null;
    }

    printf("Initially:\n");
    printf("1. Number of buckets = %d\n",buckets);
    printf("2. Load factor (alpha) = %4.2f\n", alpha);
    printf("_______________________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number of values to be hashed in the table.\n");
    scanf("%d",&total);

    //Peripheral routines to hash random integers into hash table
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        int temp = rand() % maxLen;
        //printf("%4d  ",i);
        insert(hashTable, copy, temp);
        //printf("buckets = %4d  filled = %4d  alpha = %4.2f\n\n",buckets, filled, alpha);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Following is a list of operation and the respective commands:\n\n");
    printf(" 1. Insert - i\n 2. Search - s\n 3. Delete - d\n 4. Exit - e\n\n");
    char option;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c",&option);
        if (option == 'e')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (option == 'i')
        {
            printf("Please enter the value to be inserted : ");
            scanf("%d",&val);
            insert(hashTable, copy, val);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (option == 's')
        {
            printf("Please enter the value to be searched : ");
            scanf("%d",&val);
            search(hashTable, val);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (option == 'd')
        {
            printf("Please enter the value to be deleted : ");
            scanf("%d",&val);
            delete(hashTable, val);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    free(hashTable);
    return(0);
}

void insert(Cell *a, Cell* copy, int key)    // Method of linear probing
{
    int lt, rt, shift, hashKey;
    alpha = (float)(filled + 1)/buckets;
    if (alpha >= 0.75) { rehash(a, copy); }

    lt = hashKey = key % buckets;
    printf("Key = %4d  Hashed at = %4d  ", key, lt);

    while (a[hashKey].flag == occupied)
    {
        if (a[hashKey].key == key)
        {
            printf("Key already present in table at %4d.\n",hashKey);
            return;
        }
        hashKey = (hashKey + 1) % buckets;
    }
    rt = hashKey;
    a[hashKey].key = key;
    a[hashKey].flag = occupied;
    if (rt >= lt) shift = rt - lt;
    else          shift = buckets - lt + rt;

    printf("Placed at = %4d  Shift = %4d\n", rt, shift);
    filled++;
    alpha = (float)filled/buckets;
    return;
}

int search(Cell* a, int key)
{
    int hashKey = key % buckets;
    while (a[hashKey].flag != null)
    {
        if (a[hashKey].key == key)
        {
            if (a[hashKey].flag == occupied)
            {
                printf("Element found in table at position %d.\n", hashKey);
                return hashKey;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Element not found in table.\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        hashKey = (hashKey + 1)% buckets;
    }
    printf("Element not found in table.\n");
    return -1;
}

void delete(Cell* a, int key)
{
    int hashKey = search(a, key);
    if (hashKey == -1) return;
    a[hashKey].flag = deleted;
    filled--;
    alpha = (float)filled/buckets;
    printf("Element has been deleted from the table.\n");
    return;
}

void rehash(Cell* a, Cell* copy)
{
    if (buckets == maxLen)
    {
        printf("Table size cannot exceed 8191.\n");
        return;
    }
    int i = 0, temp = 0, count = 0, num = buckets, hashKey;
    buckets = nextPrime(2*num);
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Due to load factor(alpha) exceeding 0.75, table resized to %d\n\n",buckets);

    copy = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));
    for (i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        copy[i].key = -100;
        copy[i].flag = null;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].flag != occupied)
        {
            //printf("Unoccupied: \n");
            //printf("   a: index = %4d  key = %4d  flag = %4d  count = %4d\n",i,a[i].key, a[i].flag, count);
            //printf("copy: index = %4d  key = %4d  flag = %4d  count = %4d\n\n",hashKey,copy[i].key, copy[i].flag, count);
            continue;
        }
        temp = a[i].key;
        hashKey = temp % buckets;
        while (copy[hashKey].flag == occupied)
        {
            hashKey = (hashKey + 1) % buckets;
        }
        copy[hashKey].key = temp;
        copy[hashKey].flag = occupied;
        count++;
        //printf("Occupied: \n");
        //printf("   a: index = %4d  key = %4d  flag = %4d  count = %4d\n", i, a[i].key, a[i].flag, count);
        //printf("copy: index = %4d  key = %4d  flag = %4d  count = %4d\n\n", hashKey, copy[hashKey].key, copy[hashKey].flag, count);
    }
    free(a);
    a = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));
    for (i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        a[i].key = -100;
        a[i].flag = null;
    }
    a = copy;
    free(copy);
    filled = count;
    alpha = (float)filled/buckets;
}

int nextPrime(int n)
{
    int num = n+1;  // parameter n is even, hence +1 to make it odd.
    while(!isPrime(num)) num += 2;
    return num;
}

int isPrime(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int a = sqrt(n);
    for (i = 3; i <= a; i++)
        if (n % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You might like to compile with symbols and the run your code in a debugger. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks alk for the reference. I read it and infact, for newbies like me, it would be a great learning technique. But here, perhaps I was unable to frame my question specifically despite having a specific doubt which M Oehm points out, i.e., how malloc affected the pointer to array that I passed in the function and how it can be taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `rehash`, you pass the old and new has arrays as pointer. You also do some rather strage things at the end of your function:

```
void rehash(Cell* a, Cell* copy)
{
    // determine new bucket size

    copy = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));
    // copy entries

    free(a);
    a = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));     // (a)
    for (i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        a[i].key = -100;
        a[i].flag = null;
    }
    a = copy;
    free(copy);     // (b)
}
```

Let's look at the end first. At (a), you allocate space, initialise everything and then immediately overwrite `a` with the copy, effectively giving up the handle to the new memory. (Also, why initialise at the end? Is that a leftover from copying and pasting?) Skip the allocation and initialisation.

Next, you assign the handle of `copy` to `a`. These arrays are now the same. When you free them at (b), you free both.

Get rid of everything after `free(a);`

Because you have passed the hash arrays as pointers, the calling function cannot know about the change you make. In functions where you change the contents of arrays, it is enough to pass a pointer. But `malloc` changes the pointer itself, so at least `copy` should be a pointer to pointer. Better yet, you can just pass the original array:

```
void rehash(Cell **a)
{
    // determine new bucket size

    Cell *copy = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));
    // copy entries

    free(*a);
    *a = copy;      // now the new array is in effect
}
```

Alternatively, you could return the new pointer. (You can do that safely withz `malloc`ed memory, but not with local arrays.) So your function might look like:

```
Cell *rehash(const Cell *a)
{
    // determine new bucket size

    copy = malloc(buckets * sizeof(Cell));
    // copy entries

    free(a);
    return copy;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
a = rehash(a);
```

There is no need for `copy` outside the `rehash` function, so you shouldn't pass it to `insert`, for example.

Comment: @M Oehm Thanks for the reply and also the explanation. I tried the methods you suggested. But in the second one, compiler shows an error: **expected identifier or '(' before 'void' ** in the function declaration Cell *void rehash(const Cell *a)

Comment: Aha, copy and paste blunder on my part. (I've written the second snippet based on the first one and have kept the original `void` in.) I've fixed it.

Comment: @M Oehm Still an error comes up. **  In function 'rehash': error : incompatible type for argument 1 of 'free' free(*a); **

Comment: Also, there is a note that states that : expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'Cell'
_CRTIMP void __cdec1 __MINGW_NOTHROW free (void*);
Could you also explain what this note? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the same c&p again: `free(*a)` works with `Cell **a`. For `Cell *a` it must be `free(a)`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to get this right. Besides the help from the above answer, another thing to be taken care of was that the call of rehashing was given from insert function in which case the new (bigger size) table was returned to the insert function. But the insert function did not return anything to the main function. Therefore, to deal with this, I came across the following three ways:

1. As suggested above, the argument passed to the void functions should
   be pointer to a pointer since here malloc() function is involved.
2. Call the rehash function from the main without involving the insert
   function.
3. Let insert function also return the new hash table received from
   rehashing function.

Below is the code for the third method.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define null 0
#define occupied 1
#define deleted 2
#define maxLen 8191

typedef struct cell
{
    int key;
    short flag;
} Cell;

void insert(Cell *a, int key);
int search(Cell *a, int key);
void delete(Cell *a, int key);
Cell* rehash(Cell *a);
int nextPrime(int n);
int isPrime(int n);

int buckets = 31;
int filled = 0;
float alpha = 0.0;

int main()
{
    int i, total, val;
    printf("\nHashing with linear probing\n");
    printf("_______________________________________________________________\n\n");

    Cell *hashTable;
    hashTable = (Cell*)calloc(buckets, sizeof(Cell));


    printf("Initially:\n");
    printf("1. Number of buckets = %d\n",buckets);
    printf("2. Load factor (alpha) = %4.2f\n", alpha);
    printf("_______________________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number of values to be hashed in the table.\n");
    scanf("%d",&total);

    //Peripheral routines to hash random integers into hash table
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        int temp = rand() % maxLen;
        //printf("%4d  ",i);

        alpha = (float)(filled + 1)/buckets;

        //Rehashing in case of alpha >= 0.75
        if (alpha >= 0.75) { hashTable = rehash(hashTable); }
        insert(hashTable, temp);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Following is a list of operation and the respective commands:\n\n");
    printf(" 1. Insert - i\n 2. Search - s\n 3. Delete - d\n 4. Exit - e\n\n");
    char option;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c",&option);
        if (option == 'e')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (option == 'i')
        {
            alpha = (float)(filled + 1)/buckets;

            //Rehashing in case of alpha >= 0.75
            if (alpha >= 0.75) { hashTable = rehash(hashTable); }
            printf("Please enter the value to be inserted : ");
            scanf("%d",&val);
            insert(hashTable, val);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (option == 's')
        {
            printf("Please enter the value to be searched : ");
            scanf("%d",&val);
            search(hashTable, val);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (option == 'd')
        {
            printf("Please enter the value to be deleted : ");
            scanf("%d",&val);
            delete(hashTable, val);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    free(hashTable);
    return(0);
}

void insert(Cell *a, int key)    // Method of linear probing
{
    int lt, rt, shift, hashKey;
    lt = hashKey = key % buckets;
    printf("Key = %4d  Hashed at = %4d  ", key, lt);

    while (a[hashKey].flag == occupied)
    {
        if (a[hashKey].key == key)
        {
            printf("Key already present in table at %4d.\n",hashKey);
            return;
        }
        hashKey = (hashKey + 1) % buckets;
    }
    rt = hashKey;
    a[hashKey].key = key;
    a[hashKey].flag = occupied;
    if (rt >= lt) shift = rt - lt;
    else          shift = buckets - lt + rt;

    printf("Placed at = %4d  Shift = %4d\n", rt, shift);
    filled++;
    alpha = (float)filled/buckets;
    return;
}

int search(Cell *a, int key)
{
    int hashKey = key % buckets;
    while (a[hashKey].flag != null)
    {
        if (a[hashKey].key == key)
        {
            if (a[hashKey].flag == occupied)
            {
                printf("Element found in table at position %d.\n", hashKey);
                return hashKey;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Element not found in table.\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        hashKey = (hashKey + 1)% buckets;
    }
    printf("Element not found in table.\n");
    return -1;
}

void delete(Cell *a, int key)
{
    int hashKey = search(a, key);
    if (hashKey == -1) return;
    a[hashKey].flag = deleted;
    filled--;
    alpha = (float)filled/buckets;
    printf("Element has been deleted from the table.\n");
    return;
}

Cell* rehash(Cell* a)
{
    if (buckets == maxLen)
    {
        printf("Table size cannot exceed 8191.\n");
        return;
    }
    int num = buckets;
    buckets = nextPrime(2*num);
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Due to load factor(alpha) exceeding 0.75, table resized to %d\n\n",buckets);

    int i = 0, temp = 0, count = 0;
    Cell* copy;
    copy = (Cell*)calloc(buckets, sizeof(Cell));
    if (copy == NULL) {
        perror("Failed calloc() for copy");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].flag != occupied) continue;

        temp = a[i].key;
        insert(copy, temp);
        count++;
    }
    free(a);

    filled = count;
    alpha = (float)filled/buckets;
    return copy;
}

int nextPrime(int n)
{
    int num = n+1;  // parameter n is even, hence +1 to make it odd.
    while(!isPrime(num)) num += 2;
    return num;
}

int isPrime(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int a = sqrt(n);
    for (i = 3; i <= a; i++)
        if (n % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```